# Trying to select large text field from database using Perl DBI, and it only selects the first bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl, dbi

I am using Perl to parse through a large number of rich text "files" (stored as ntext - a datatype that is pretty much a mystery to me) which live in a SQL Server database, which I am pretty new to, having previously only worked with Oracle. However, I am only getting the first ~40 characters back from each file. Each file begins something like this:

```
{\rtf1\sste17000\ansi\deflang1033\ftnbj\uc1\deff0 {\fonttbl{\f0 \fswiss Arial;} etc.
```

But when I'm selecting from within Perl, they cut off like this:

```
{\rtf1\sste17000\ansi\deflang1033\ftnbj
```

Here is the code I have right now (select statement obviously simplified for brevity):

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;UID=$user;PWD=$password")
    or die "Can't connect to server: $DBI::errstr";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select note_txt from database")
    or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
my @data;

$sth->execute()
    or die "Couldn't execute statement: " . $sth->errstr;

$sth->{'LongTruncOk'} = 1;
$sth->{'LongReadLen'} = 2000;
while (@data = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    my $note = $data[0];
    parse_note($note);
}
```

Why is it only giving me the first ~40 characters, and how can I get out the entire text?

Thanks!

Comment: According to the [DBI docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#LongReadLen), "Changing the value of `LongReadLen` for a statement handle after it has been `prepare`'d will typically have no effect, so it's common to set `LongReadLen` on the `$dbh` before calling `prepare`." Does that fix your issue?

Comment: That appears to have done the trick! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue with DBI::ODBC and I would change the code on the database handle, not the statement handle.  Using your code it would now look like such (noticed the `LongReadLen` has been moved up in the code and I suggest using the database handle `$dbh`, not the statement handle `$sth`):

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;UID=$user;PWD=$password")
    or die "Can't connect to server: $DBI::errstr";

$dbh->{LongTruncOk} = 1;
$dbh->{LongReadLen} = 2000;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select note_txt from database")
    or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;
my @data;

$sth->execute()
    or die "Couldn't execute statement: " . $sth->errstr;

while (@data = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    my $note = $data[0];
    parse_note($note);
}
```

You may also want to adjust the `$dbh->{'LongReadLen'} = 2000;` to be higher.  Each situation is, of course, different but in my case I used 16K i.e. `$dbh->{'LongReadLen'} = 16384;`

Here is also a little code stub with comments from the book *Programming the Perl DBI*:

```
$dbh->{LongReadLen} = 512 * 1024;  ### We are interested in the first 512 KB of data
$dbh->{LongTruncOk} = 1;    ### We're happy to truncate any excess
```

NOTE: I also don't believe the single quotes are necessary.  So `$dbh->{'LongReadLen'}` becomes `$dbh->{LongReadLen}`.
Also, as mentioned by the user *@ThisSuitIsBlackNot* in the comments, please refer to the [DBI docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#LongReadLen) for further clarification and information.

Comment: Nice answer. You might also want to mention that this behavior is actually documented in the [DBI docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#LongReadLen).

Comment: I will.  I'll add that to my answer.  Thx.